# Lazy loading in jqxListBox

Tags: jqwidget

Can anyone help to implement lazy loading in `jqxListBox`? There is no built API for this. I have to display 10000 records in `jqxListBox`. Due to this huge dataset, the selection and remaining business logic become very slow.

[image]

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: you can check the demo sections, there is a pagination demo which helps you t split the list into multiple pages using pagination.

https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/php/index.htm#demos/php/serverpaging.htm

Comment: @KUMAR Ya I already went through all demos but there is no pagination for jqxList. They are given pagination for jqxGrid only.